# Is there a difference between Wordpress Multisite (WPMU) and Wordpress, with respects to the hooks and the action reference (API)?

Tags: wordpress

The Wordpress documentation isn't clear about this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

What I specifically need to know is whether `add_action("publish_post", "myCallbackFunction")` is a hook that will apply across the entire Multisite network, or simply on an individual page (or merely for admins).

What I want is that `myCallbackFunction` is triggered whenever *any* of the bloggers on the Multisite network clicks the button to publish a blog post.

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'publish_post'` is not attached to a single page (even on a non-Multisite install).

The `'publish_post'` hook is run by the WordPress core whenever a post is published. As long as this hook and the callback are part of an active theme or plugin (that exists across all multisite instances), they will run whenever a post is published.

Comment: It seems it's not only run when a post is published, but also run every time someone updates a post. Do you know a function which only runs on the first publish?

Comment: You're correct. I believe `draft_to_publish` will be a suitable substitute.

Comment: Great! You don't happen to also know a seperate function that only runs on updates? I'm mapping these to the create and update functions in an external API.

Comment: I believe you can use [`edit_post`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Post.2C_Page.2C_Attachment.2C_and_Category_Actions_.28Admin.29)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found that I had to use `publish_to_publish` for it to trigger only when a published post is updated. Since `edit_post` would trigger when the post is first created, when `draft_to_publish` is also triggered.